# Elegant way to use map for a scoring discrete variable

Tags: dictionary, pandas, scoring

I have a huge score card data [200k records] and actual student data [~100M]. I'm trying to use map function to convert a discrete value in the dataset to a numeric score.

I'm converting the score to dict object to accomplish this. Is there a better way to accomplish the same without converting the score card to dict or any other object

```
#Score card Data
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'math_grade': ['A', 'B','MISS'], 
        'score': [1, 2, 3]} 
df_math_grade = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['math_grade', 'score'])

#Convert Score card to dictionary
di = df_math_grade.set_index('math_grade')['score'].to_dict()

#STUDENT MARKS DATA
student_marks = {
        'STUDENT_ID': ['S1', 'S2', 'S3','S4','S5'],
        'MATH_GRADE': ['A','B','C','X','MISS']}
student_marks = pd.DataFrame(student_marks, columns = ['STUDENT_ID', 'MATH_GRADE'])

student_marks["MATH_GRADE_SCORE"] = student_marks["MATH_GRADE"].map(di)

student_marks
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
print (pd.merge(student_marks, 
                df_math_grade,
                left_on='MATH_GRADE', 
                right_on='math_grade', 
                how='left').drop('math_grade', axis=1))

  STUDENT_ID MATH_GRADE  score
0         S1          A    1.0
1         S2          B    2.0
2         S3          C    NaN
3         S4          X    NaN
4         S5       MISS    3.0
```

EDIT:

Another solution is [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series`, only omit `to_dict`:

```
s = df_math_grade.set_index('math_grade')['score']
print (s)
math_grade
A       1
B       2
MISS    3
Name: score, dtype: int64

student_marks["MATH_GRADE_SCORE"] = student_marks["MATH_GRADE"].map(di)
student_marks["MATH_GRADE_SCORE1"] = student_marks.MATH_GRADE.map(s)
print (student_marks )
  STUDENT_ID MATH_GRADE  MATH_GRADE_SCORE  MATH_GRADE_SCORE1
0         S1          A               1.0                1.0
1         S2          B               2.0                2.0
2         S3          C               NaN                NaN
3         S4          X               NaN                NaN
4         S5       MISS               3.0                3.0
```

Comment: actually i want to loop this over several columns using a simple  function, so i'm avoiding joins and i want to it to be minimal. My question is -can i use map function using data frame instead of dict?

Comment: I think remap by `dict` in one of very nice solutions, I add map by `Serie`, please check my answer.